# Cycliness of finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field. I have difficulty understanding the proof of its cycliness. Using the structural theorem for $G$, $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/d_1\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}/d_n$ with $1<d_1|\cdots|d_n$. Then all elements of $G$ satisfies $d_1x=0$ (or written multiplicatively, $x^{d_1}=1$). But since $x^{d_1}=1$ has at most $d_1$ roots, $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/d_1.$ But where does we use the information of $G$? Why doesn't this yield the absurd conclusion that $\mathbb{Z}/d_1\times\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}/d_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/d_1$?

Comment: It does yield that conclusion, and it's not absurd if $n=1$.

You use that $G$ is a subgroup of a field when you say that a polynomial can only have as many roots as its degree.

Comment: Isn't it $x^{d_n}=1$?